# React native scroll + animation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I created an application in react native in this application I have one bottom tab and on the screen of the bottom tab there is a tab bar navigation and above this tab bat i had set one sticky header (it's my bottom navigator screen).

I have set animation on this header based on the tab bar screen scroll means to hide and show "clamp", My other tab has an independent stack navigator (it's my stack navigator screen that's rendered in the tab navigator) and it's also have some sub screen in this tab

I want when I go on any sub-screen of another tab at a time my animation is already fired means my sticky header is hide based on previous screen and if i do scroll in this screen it's work like it's happen first time

my tab navigator

```
switch (route. key) {
  case "first":
    return <Dashboard position={position} firstRef={firstRef} />;
  case "second":
    return <Navigator1 position={position} secondRef={secondRef} />;
  default:
    return null;
}
```

Navigator 1

```
<NavigationContainer independent>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen1">
      {props => (
      <SCREEN1 {...props} position={position} secondRef={secondRef} />
      )}
    </Stack.Screen>
    <Stack.Screen name="screen2">
      {props => (
      <SCREEN2 {...props} position={position} secondRef={secondRef} />
      )}
    </Stack.Screen>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

My screen1

```
 <AnimatedScrollView position={position} ref={secondRef}>
       My scroll view contains...
 </AnimatedScrollView>
```

I want it when I do scroll from screen1 at the time only it's effect